# Javascript - regular expression to split string on unescaped character, e.g. | but ignore \|

Tags: javascript, regex

I read a string from file that I split on | character. For example the string is

```
1|test pattern|prefix|url|postfix
```

So split must always give me 5 substrings, which in the above case are

```
["1", "test pattern", "prefix", "url", "postfix"]
```

The problem comes in when any of these five substrings contains | character. I would store it as escaped \|

```
1|test pattern|prefix|url \| title |postfix
```

Now, you can see that string.split('|') won't give me the desired result. The desired result is

```
["1", "test pattern", "prefix", "url \| title ", "postfix"]
```

I have tried some regular expressions but none of these gives desired result.

```
string.split(/[^\\]\|/)  //["", "", "prefi", "$url \| $titl", " postfix"]
```

It looks like this is only possible with negative lookbacks but I could not get one to work

Comment: I take it you don't have control over the character being used within the string to separate the elements?

Comment: Your string yields:
>> var word = '1|test pattern|prefix|url \| title |postfix'; 
>> word 
"1|test pattern|prefix|url | title |postfix"
Did you mean to have it as '1|test pattern|prefix|url \\| title |postfix' instead?

Comment: @Patrick: I cannot change the delimeter, because now it has been used in many files but I can change the escape character \

Comment: Why have you checked a broken answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution:

```
"1|test pattern|prefix|url \\| title |postfix"
.replace(/([^\\])\|/g, "$1$1|")
.split(/[^\\]\|/);
```

That said, you'll need to escape your backslash in the initial string with another backslash to make it work:

```
"1|test pattern|prefix|url \\| title |postfix"
                           ^
```

Working demo available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5stR/).

Comment: This works for the string mentioned in the question but fails for

    1|test pattern|prefix|url \\|\\| title |postfix

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Javascript does not support lookbehinds. I see no easy solution but the following might be suitable as workaround:

```
// use two backslashes in your string!
var string = '1|test pattern|prefix|url \\| title |postfix';

// create an arbitrary unique substitute character
var sub = "-";

string.replace(/\\\|/g,sub).split(/\|/);

/* replace the substituted character again in your array of strings */
```

Alternatively you could use something like this:

```
string.split(//\|\b//)
```

However this might fail in some circumstances when there are whitespaces involved.

Comment: a simple `boundary` would do it..no need for `replace`

Comment: @Anirudha I added it as an option but it will fail with whitespaces.

Comment: @Christoph This is the closest what I could think of. But problem is that any character used as arbitrary separator may also occur in text in any of the substring

Comment: @Kashif well, you can just use the boundary regex or sp00m's solution which is far more elegant and robust.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `split()` you could match all occurences that you're interested in:

```
var rx = /([^\\\|]|\\\|?)+/gi, item, items = [];
while (item = rx.exec(str)) {
    items.push(item[0]);
}
```

See it in action in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uJYm/)

Comment: +1 for nice idea to handle the problem
The solution does not work completely though, there are some unexpected empty elements

Comment: @Kashif, yeah, I missed the `[0]` on the item, see http://jsfiddle.net/3uJYm/ for it working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
'foo|bar\\|baz'.match(/(\\\||[^|])+/g)
```

This finds all sequences of characters that comprise the *escaped splitting character* or any character that isn't the splitting character.